# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when trying to log my $refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know where I'm wrong here but it my console it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.selectFile (vSingleUpload.vue?cf02:23)

But in my UI it doesn't crash or anything it renders without errors.

---

```
    <template>
  <section>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <v-file-input label="file input" type="file" @change="selectFile" ref="userFile"></v-file-input>
        </v-form>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: ""
    };
  },

  methods: {
    selectFile: function() {
      this.file = this.$refs.userFile.files[0];
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-file-input` doesn't expose a `files` property, so `this.$refs.userFile.files` will be `undefined`.

You can get the file directly as the argument passed to your event listener, like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  methods: {
    selectFile (file) {
      console.log(file)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@3.9.97/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.18/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.18/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <v-file-input label="file input" @change="selectFile"></v-file-input>
        </v-form>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The `ref` is not required, nor is the `type="file"`.